# Has control db transaction by self in Orchard webapi

Tags: transactions, orchardcms, eventhandler

In my apicontroller, it trigger an event. And in that event handler, I use New and Create functions in ContentManager to create contentitem. But seems that the transaction never be committed when the controller finish. The database never has the item that I created.

It have to use transactoinmanager.requeirednew()　function to commit the trans explicitly in order to complete the creation.(Then the created contentitem shows in database)

I just want to confirm that if it has to control the db transaction by myself in Orchard custom api controller or triggering event in apicontroller is another situation that out of the Orchard transaction mechanism control.

I use Orchard version 1.10.2

Edit:
Below is my controller to trigger the event

```
public class TradeAddedEventApiController:ApiController,IDependency
{
    IMyEvents _myEventHandler;
    public TradeAddedEventApiController(IMyEvents eventHandler)
    {
        _myEventHandler = eventHandler;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void Post(int managerId, string managerIp, [FromBody]TradeRecord record)
    {
        _myEventHandler.OnTradeAdded(managerId, managerIp, record);
    }

    public string Get()
    {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Below is my event handler:

```
public class MyOrderEventHandler : IMyEvents
{
    Work<A2AFollowCacheService> _a2aCacheService;
    Work<IContentManager> _contentManager;
    Work<ITransactionManager> _trasansctionManager;
    Work<OrderMapService> _orderMapService;
    Work<MTManagerHTTP> _managerApi;
    public MyOrderEventHandler(Work<A2AFollowCacheService> a2aCacheService,Work<IContentManager> contentManager,
        Work<OrderMapService> orderMapService,Work<MTManagerHTTP> managerApi, Work<ITransactionManager> trasansctionManager)
    {
        _a2aCacheService = a2aCacheService;
        _contentManager = contentManager;
        _orderMapService = orderMapService;
        _managerApi = managerApi;
        _trasansctionManager = trasansctionManager;
    }

    public void OnTickPrice(int managerId, string managerIp, List<SymbolInfo> priceInfoList)
    {
        ;
    }

    public void OnTradeAdded(int managerId, string managerIp, TradeRecord trade)
    {
        if (trade == null)
            return;
        var followList = _a2aCacheService.Value.GetPart(trade.Login, managerIp);
        if (followList == null)
            return;
        var contentManager = _contentManager.Value;
        var managerApi = _managerApi.Value;
        foreach (var item in followList)
        {
            foreach (var targetAccount in item.TargetAccountList)
            {
                var localTransRecord = contentManager.New<CopyTransactionRecordPart>(CopyTransactionRecordConstants.ContentType);
                localTransRecord.CopyTradeId = item.Id;
                localTransRecord.ManagerId = managerId;
                localTransRecord.ManagerIp = managerIp;
                localTransRecord.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
                localTransRecord.OriginalTicket = trade.Order;
                var mtTrans = new TradeTransInfo();
                mtTrans.Cmd = trade.Cmd;
                mtTrans.Comment = "copy order from" + trade.Order;
                mtTrans.Price = trade.OpenPrice;
                mtTrans.Symbol = trade.Symbol;
                mtTrans.Type = TradeTransactionType.BrOrderOpen;
                mtTrans.Volume = trade.Volume;
                mtTrans.OrderBy = (int)targetAccount.AccountNumber;
                contentManager.Create(localTransRecord, VersionOptions.Published);
            }                
        }
        _trasansctionManager.Value.RequireNew();
    }

    public void OnTradeClosed(int managerId, string managerIp, TradeRecord trade)
    {
        ;
    }

    public void OnTradeDeleted(int managerId, string managerIp, TradeRecord trade)
    {
        ;
    }

    public void OnTradeUpdated(int managerId, string managerIp, TradeRecord trade)
    {
        ;
    }
}
```

When I remove "_trasansctionManager.Value.RequireNew()" then the contentitem would not be created even I Published it

Comment: I can't be sure without seeing your code but I suspect that you simply have to use the `Publish` method to commit the new ContentItem.

Comment: @Lawyerson Thanks for the reply. pasted the code.

Comment: Below the line `contentManager.Create(localTransRecord, VersionOptions.Published);` try adding: `contentManager.Publish(localTransRecord.ContentItem);`. I'm not sure if that'll do the trick but I think it should.